# Defending against Azure SQL data leakage from within a corporate network

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-security

I have question around DLP (data leakage prevention) from a corporate network.

I have a Virtual Machine on a corporate network. The VM can access an Azure SQL DB in the cloud: aaa.database.windows.net through a connection over port 1433.

However, I don't want that same VM to connect to bbb.database.windows.net.

Azure offers no guarantees on the public IP (both servers could appear as the same IP) - what technology can I use on the corporate's perimeter network/firewall to permit access to aaa but disallow access to bbb?

The attack I am concerned about is someone internal to the company querying data out of aaa and inserting it in to bbb. For example, if the one server is ourcorporatedate.database.windows.net and the other is somerandom.database.windows.net the someone internal to the company could take corporate data and write it to some random database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual Network service endpoints and rules. Virtual network rules are one firewall security feature that controls whether your Azure SQL Database or SQL Data Warehouse server accepts communications that are sent from particular subnets in virtual networks. Learn how to use it and benefits/limitations on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview) documentation.

Comment: This doesnt address the problem. SSMS connectivity from on-prem to azure SQL still uses the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

If database aaa and bbb have the same public IP address. I think there is not a good way to set in the on-premise firewall to permit access to aaa but deny access to bbb. From the same client, the firewall rule will have the same source IP, protocol, port, and destination IP for outbound traffic.

If you want to selectively grant access to just one of the databases in your Azure SQL server, you can only create a database-level rule for the required database. Also, Specify an IP address range for the database firewall rule that is beyond the IP address range specified in the server-level firewall rule, and ensure that the IP address of the client falls in the range specified in the database-level rule. Server level rules allow access to the Azure SQL Server. Which means that the client will have access to all the databases stored on that SQL Server. Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure).

Comment: Hi, it is not about restricting access to our databases, it is about preventing egress to others. And yes, they could be the same IP. TDS packet inspection seems like an option

Comment: If so, I agree TDS packet inspection might be the right direction. Network-layer could not make preventing egress to others. The application layer restrict in corporate's perimeter network/firewall could help. I am not an expert in on-premise firewall, you may get help in your corporate's firewall technical experts.

Comment: Thanks Nancy, I have reached out to them.

Answer (score 0):

The current VPN feature in SQL Azure does not directly prevent this (but please look for future updates where this is planned for the service endpoints feature for SQL Azure).  However, there are various mitigations you can use to detect or reduce the ability to do this:

1. You can enable auditing on the aaa database.  This can detect all logins and major state changes to the DB.   (Detect)
2. You can reduce the permissions for various kinds of users on the database to the bare minimum and use features which further reduce the size of the data that a customer can copy out of the database at all.  This includes row-level security, data masking, always encrypted (which you would lock down to a specific app/user to be able to decrypt sensitive data in the client - other clients without the key just get cypertext), etc.
3. Use firewall rules (as stated in the other answers) to restrict which clients can connect to the database at all - then you can restrict where they can connect with permissions.

Please note that SQL Azure's logical servers do not generally imply that every customer database in that server has the same IP.  Currently there is a knob in service endpoints (docs page is currently down so I can't get you a link atm) to configure whether you go through the per-region gateway or not.  If you don't (recommended), you would see the IP of the hosting node and this can change over time.  The Service endpoints feature will give VPN users more control for network-level rules going forward, but some of these features have not yet landed in production.  I encourage you to mitigate with other steps (above) until that is available to you.

Comment: Thanks Conor. Unfortunately this is not really about locking down a DB, but more about protecting uploads to some other DB from the corp network.

Comment: You do have the ability to block access using your firewall rules to azure generally from your network except from within a VPN.  So, that would give you one lever to restrict access to azure except from VPNs.  Not all services might work correctly in such a model today, but that's available to you.  You have this issue with any general IP address on the Internet, so you are mostly left with trying to scan packets or similar.  Since SQL Azure uses TLS 1.2 by default, you would not likely see anything except attempts to open sockets to the Azure IP range.